# Jandex Maven Plugin Not Generating jandex.idx for Test Classes (v1.0.6)

Tags: testing, jandex

I am using below Jandex Maven Plugin to create jandex.ix files for test classes.
Jandex Maven Plugin not generating the jandex.idx file for test classes. Ideally after the execution of this plugin

I used below jandex dependency
 
org.jboss
jandex
3.1.6
``

and below plugin for generating jandex.idx file for test classes
`<plugin> <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId> <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId> <version>1.0.6</version> <executions> <execution> <id>index-test-classes</id> <goals> <goal>jandex</goal> </goals> <phase>test-classes</phase> </execution> </executions> </plugin>`
Expectation: It should create jandex.idx file under target/test-classes/jandex.idx after plugin execution

Comment: To generate a `jandex.idx` file for test classes with the Jandex Maven Plugin, ensure the plugin is correctly configured in your `pom.xml`. The plugin should be set to run during the `test-classes` phase. U can check:
1. **Project Structure**: Ensure test classes are located in the standard directory `src/test/java`
2. **Plugin Configuration**: Verify the plugin's configuration in `pom.xml` for any errors.
3. **Jandex Version**: Confirm compatibility of Jandex version with the Maven plugin.
4. **Build Logs**: Examine Maven build logs for any errors or warnings related to the Jandex plugin.